# xml file fails to import

Tags: xml, excel, import

I am trying to convert an xml file from drugbank downloads. Whenever I try to import it in excel 2007 it says fails to import. Maybe it is because of the size. Can anyone suggest if there is any other way I can get this file to open so I can save it as tab-delim? Its the first file(All Drugs, including target, transporter, carrier, and enzyme information) here , http://www.drugbank.ca/downloads in xml format

Comment: If you are familiar with programming and XSLT, that could be used to convert the XML to a tab delimited file.

Comment: @Lumos Lumos.  I do not know if you are informed if an answer is amended.  This comment is to ensure you know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete rewrite of my original answer.

For my original answer I undertook a limited analysis of drugbank.xml.  I hedged a little but stated that the structure was too complex to be converted to any standard tab delimited file.  By this, I meant that a tab delimited file that could be processed by any standard program.  I stand by that statement but it possible to create a non-standard delimited file that might be useful.

The table below shows the structure of drugbank.xml.

The columns are Index, Level, Name, Parent and Repeats.  For elements drug and partner, Repeats is the actual number of repeats.  For the other elements, it is the maximum number of repeats within an occurrence of its parent.

```
Inx Lvl Name------------------------------------ Pnt Repeats
  1   1   drugs                                    0       1
  2   2     drug                                   1    6711
  3   3       drugbank-id                          2       1
  4   3       name                                 2       1
  5   3       description                          2       1
  6   3       cas-number                           2       1
  7   3       general-references                   2       1
  8   3       synthesis-reference                  2       1
  9   3       indication                           2       1
 10   3       pharmacology                         2       1
 11   3       mechanism-of-action                  2       1
 12   3       toxicity                             2       1
 13   3       biotransformation                    2       1
 14   3       absorption                           2       1
 15   3       half-life                            2       1
 16   3       protein-binding                      2       1
 17   3       route-of-elimination                 2       1
 18   3       volume-of-distribution               2       1
 19   3       clearance                            2       1
 20   3       secondary-accession-numbers          2       1
 21   4         secondary-accession-number        20       5
 22   3       groups                               2       1
 23   4         group                             22       3
 24   3       taxonomy                             2       1
 25   4         kingdom                           24       1
 26   4         substructures                     24       1
 27   5           substructure                    26      35
 28   3       synonyms                             2       1
 29   4         synonym                           28      82
 30   3       salts                                2       1
 31   4         salt                              30      17
 32   3       brands                               2       1
 33   4         brand                             32     230
 34   3       mixtures                             2       1
 35   4         mixture                           34     340
 36   5           name                            35       1
 37   5           ingredients                     35       1
 38   3       packagers                            2       1
 39   4         packager                          38     173
 40   5           name                            39       1
 41   5           url                             39       1
 42   3       manufacturers                        2       1
 43   4         manufacturer                      42      91
 44   3       prices                               2       1
 45   4         price                             44     172
 46   5           description                     45       1
 47   5           cost                            45       1
 48   5           unit                            45       1
 49   3       categories                           2       1
 50   4         category                          49      11
 51   3       affected-organisms                   2       1
 52   4         affected-organism                 51       3
 53   3       dosages                              2       1
 54   4         dosage                            53      22
 55   5           form                            54       1
 56   5           route                           54       1
 57   5           strength                        54       1
 58   3       atc-codes                            2       1
 59   4         atc-code                          58      36
 60   3       ahfs-codes                           2       1
 61   4         ahfs-code                         60      11
 62   3       patents                              2       1
 63   4         patent                            62       5
 64   5           number                          63       1
 65   5           country                         63       1
 66   5           approved                        63       1
 67   5           expires                         63       1
 68   3       food-interactions                    2       1
 69   4         food-interaction                  68       6
 70   3       drug-interactions                    2       1
 71   4         drug-interaction                  70     246
 72   5           drug                            71       1
 73   5           name                            71       1
 74   5           description                     71       1
 75   3       protein-sequences                    2       1
 76   4         protein-sequence                  75      10
 77   5           header                          76       1
 78   5           chain                           76       1
 79   3       calculated-properties                2       1
 80   4         property                          79      18
 81   5           kind                            80       1
 82   5           value                           80       1
 83   5           source                          80       1
 84   3       experimental-properties              2       1
 85   4         property                          84       4
 86   5           kind                            85       1
 87   5           value                           85       1
 88   5           source                          85       1
 89   3       external-identifiers                 2       1
 90   4         external-identifier               89      13
 91   5           resource                        90       1
 92   5           identifier                      90       1
 93   3       external-links                       2       1
 94   4         external-link                     93       4
 95   5           resource                        94       1
 96   5           url                             94       1
 97   3       targets                              2       1
 98   4         target                            97     144
 99   5           actions                         98       1
100   6             action                        99       2
101   5           references                      98       1
102   5           known-action                    98       1
103   3       enzymes                              2       1
104   4         enzyme                           103      19
105   5           actions                        104       1
106   6             action                       105       3
107   5           references                     104       1
108   3       transporters                         2       1
109   4         transporter                      108      24
110   5           actions                        109       1
111   6             action                       110       3
112   5           references                     109       1
113   3       carriers                             2       1
114   4         carrier                          113       6
115   5           actions                        114       1
116   6             action                       115       1
117   5           references                     114       1
118   2     partners                               1       1
119   3       partner                            118    4227
120   4         name                             119       1
121   4         general-function                 119       1
122   4         specific-function                119       1
123   4         gene-name                        119       1
124   4         locus                            119       1
125   4         reaction                         119       1
126   4         signals                          119       1
127   4         cellular-location                119       1
128   4         transmembrane-regions            119       1
129   4         theoretical-pi                   119       1
130   4         molecular-weight                 119       1
131   4         chromosome                       119       1
132   4         species                          119       1
133   5           category                       132       1
134   5           name                           132       1
135   5           uniprot-name                   132       1
136   5           uniprot-taxon-id               132       1
137   4         essentiality                     119       1
138   4         references                       119       1
139   4         external-identifiers             119       1
140   5           external-identifier            139       9
141   6             resource                     140       1
142   6             identifier                   140       1
143   4         synonyms                         119       1
144   5           synonym                        143      38
145   4         protein-sequence                 119       1
146   5           header                         145       1
147   5           chain                          145       1
148   4         gene-sequence                    119       1
149   5           header                         148       1
150   5           chain                          148       1
151   4         pfams                            119       1
152   5           pfam                           151      15
153   6             identifier                   152       1
154   6             name                         152       1
155   4         go-classifiers                   119       1
156   5           go-classifier                  155      49
157   6             category                     156       1
158   6             description                  156       1
```

I have a utility which I developed for a client who could not process the enormous XML documents they were being sent.  I extracted selected information to a delimited file.  Although these XML documents were enormous, the structure was simple with no repetition within the level 2 element.  I wondered if I could enhance the utility to accept repetitions and output the data to a delimited file albeit a non-standard delimited file.  I now know that I can although I am not sure how useful the delimited file is.

My output has 97 columns, one per leaf element.  There are six heading rows,one per level. which list the leaf element and its parent elements.  When a element repeats, the value is placed on the next available line.  A few columns from the rows for the first three drugs file will, I hope, make this clear.  Note that column 61 has been truncated for this display.

```
|Column 1   |Column 2    |Column 18                  |Column 25  |Column 56                   |Column 60 |Column 61                     |Column 62   |
|drugs      |drugs       |drugs                      |drugs      |drugs                       |drugs     |drugs                         |drugs       |
|drug       |drug        |drug                       |drug       |drug                        |drug      |drug                          |drug        |
|drugbank-id|name        |secondary-accession-numbers|mixtures   |external-identifiers        |targets   |targets                       |targets     |
|           |            |secondary-accession-number |mixture    |external-identifier         |target    |target                        |target      |
|           |            |                           |name       |resource                    |actions   |references                    |known-action|
|           |            |                           |           |                            |action    |                              |            |
|DB00001    |Lepirudin   |BIOD00024                  |           |Drugs Product Database (DPD)|inhibitor |# Turpie AG: Anticoagulants in|yes         |
|           |            |BTD00024                   |           |National Drug Code Directory|          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |           |PharmGKB                    |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |           |UniProtKB                   |          |                              |            |
|DB00002    |Cetuximab   |BIOD00071                  |           |National Drug Code Directory|antagonist|# Hosokawa N, Yamamoto S, Ueha|yes         |
|           |            |BTD00071                   |           |GenBank                     |          |# Snyder LC, Astsaturov I, Wei|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |PharmGKB                    |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Negri DR, Tosi E, Valota O, |unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |# Overington JP, Al-Lazikani B|unknown     |
|DB00003    |Dornase Alfa|BIOD00001                  |Cauterex   |Drugs Product Database (DPD)|          |# Cramer GW, Bosso JA: The rol|yes         |
|           |            |BTD00001                   |Clorfibrase|GenBank                     |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |Elase      |PharmGKB                    |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |Fibrabene  |UniProtKB                   |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |Fibrase SA |                            |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |Fibrolan   |                            |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |Parkelase  |                            |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |Ridasa     |                            |          |                              |            |
|           |            |                           |           |                            |          |                              |            |
```

The resultant file has 135,713 rows and is 52,171,387 bytes long.  Would this, or some simple variation, be of use?